# Balls and Bins- Heavy Loaded Case: A Tight Formula

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, balls-in-bins

I have $m=10^6$ balls and $n=13\cdot 10^3$ bins. I need to know how I can calculate maximum load for each bin. I'm aware of [1], but it's to loose (e.g. max_load: $e\cdot m/n$.  And in practice using the formula overflow does not happen as I have implemented it (in c++).

**I need a formula to get a bin max-overflow and it does not use any big $O$ notation, so I can replace my parameters and get the result**.

[1]. http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/math/czumaj-balls-into-bins.pdf

Comment: What are you trying to calculate?  Presumably the balls are placed in the bins randomly.  The max load could be as small as $10^6/(13 \cdot 3)$ or as large as $10^6$.  Are you after the most probable max load?  The 90th percentile max load?

Comment: @RossMillikan I' after minimal max-load that a bin can have with a high probability. As you said we can always set the max load to a very large number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the normal approximation.  The expected number of balls in a bin is $1000000/13000 \approx 77$.  The standard deviation is $\sqrt {10^6 \cdot \frac 1{13000} \cdot (1-\frac 1{13000})}\approx 8.77$  You expect one bin in $13000$ to be about $3.8 \sigma$ high from a z-score table, so your max bin would be around $77+3.8\cdot 8.8 \approx 111$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please mention source of the formulas (or what they are called). As I need it for my paper.

Comment: This is the [normal approximation to the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation). It should be discussed in any text.